# Python grab substring between two specific characters

Tags: python, string, loops, substring

I have a folder with hundreds of files named like:

```
"2017_05_S2B_7VEG_20170528_0_L2A_B01.tif"
```

Convention:
`year_month_ID_zone_date_0_L2A_B01.tif`   (`"_0_L2A_B01.tif"`, and `"zone"` never change)

What I need is to iterate through every file and build a path based on their name in order to download them.
For example:

```
name = "2017_05_S2B_7VEG_20170528_0_L2A_B01.tif"
path = "2017/5/S2B_7VEG_20170528_0_L2A/B01.tif"
```

The path convention needs to be: `path = year/month/ID_zone_date_0_L2A/B01.tif`

I thought of making a loop which would "cut" my string into several parts every time it encounters a `"_"` character, then stitch the different parts in the right order to create my path name.
I tried this but it didn't work:

```
import re

filename = 
"2017_05_S2B_7VEG_20170528_0_L2A_B01.tif"

try:
    found = re.search('_(.+?)_', filename).group(1)
except AttributeError:
    # _ not found in the original string
    found = '' # apply your error handling
```

How could I achieve that on Python ?

Comment: So, basically you want to replace underscore `_` with `/`, for the first two and last occurrences of `_` in the string?

Comment: Use the string split method

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the example but I'm not sure what changed between the name and path, or what was the pattern for the change - for example, unsure how the 05 got changed to 5.

Comment: That is the thing, I did not decide the convention. The months smaller than 10 don't have a "0", just 1 number. And no I don't want to just replace the _ with /, there is a reorganization of the entire string. Which is why I specified the convention in my answer: it goes from "year_month_ID_zone_date_0_L2A_B01.tif" to "year/month/year_month_ID_zone_date_0_L2A/B08.tif" (so not a substitution from "_" to "/" but a rearranging of the string)

Comment: * Mistake on the path convention: path = year/month/ID_zone_date_0_L2A/B01.tif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only have one separator character, you may as well simply use Python's built in split function:

```
import os

items = filename.split('_')
year, month = items[:2]
new_filename = '_'.join(items[2:])

path = os.path.join(year, month, new_filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code snippet

```py
filename = "2017_05_S2B_7VEG_20170528_0_L2A_B01.tif"
found = re.sub('(\d+)_(\d+)_(.*)_(.*)\.tif', r'\1/\2/\3/\4.tif', filename)
print(found) # prints 2017/05/S2B_7VEG_20170528_0_L2A/B01.tif
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a regex -- you can just use `split()`.

```
filename = "2017_05_S2B_7VEG_20170528_0_L2A_B01.tif"
parts = filename.split("_")

year = parts[0]
month = parts[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do like this:

```py
from os import listdir, mkdir
from os.path import isfile, join, isdir

my_path = 'your_soure_dir'

files_name = [f for f in listdir(my_path) if isfile(join(my_path, f))]

def create_dir(files_name):
    for file in files_name:
        month = file.split('_', '1')[0]
        week = file.split('_', '2')[1]
        if not isdir(my_path):
            mkdir(month)
            mkdir(week)
            ### your download code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = "2017_05_S2B_7VEG_20170528_0_L2A_B01.tif"
temp = filename.split('_')
result = "/".join(temp)
print(result)
```

result is
`2017/05/S2B/7VEG/20170528/0/L2A/B01.tif`